# Resize document library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, library

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I need to resize the capacity of one of the document library
how can I do that > if it's possible?

Comment: What is the capacity now? How do you gather that? A SharePoint library can have hundreds of thousands of documents. The limitation is in the list view threshold, since it is tied to the number of SQL operations on a list or library. By building filtered views that will never exceed that limit, you can have a lot more than 5000 files in a library.

Comment: cross-posted at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b2f25dd-e1e3-40fb-8630-3f0af5786813/resize-document-library - Please take a look at http://www.excelguru.ca/node/7

Answer (score 1):

If by "capacity" you actually mean the view threshold, this will give you a good idea
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinaayoub/archive/2010/04/22/sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-the-list-view-threshold.aspx

Just make sure if fits with your overall governance policies, as these are measure meant to avoid performance penalties on your farm.